# ForFiles return code 1 within Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to delete files from a 2008 Windows Server that are older than 180 days based on the last modified date. I am using ForFiles in order to attempt to do this. When I run the command interactively as domain admin on the server, the command executes. When I setup a task within Windows task scheduler, the task fails to run with a return code of 1.

The below command is the command I am running.

```
forfiles /p "E:" /s /m *.* /D -180 /c "cmd /c del @path && echo"
```

I have also tried the below:

[image]

Comment: I have already seen the question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085116/windows-2008-server-task-scheduler-does-not-run-bat-batch-job?rq=1

This solution did not work for me either. I already have the latest patches.

Comment: Return code 1 just means it didn't find any files.  Which could be correct